# Weird Types when retrieving all Types from Assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I use reflection to retrieve Types from within a namespace and do some stuff which each of them:

```
Type baseType = typeof(BaseUpdate);
            var updateTypes = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes(); 
foreach (var type in updateTypes) {
  if (type.Namespace!="myApp.Logic.Updates") continue;
  // stuff
}
```

This works fine. I retrieve all the types I want and can do stuff with them. But as an addition I also retrieve some "weird" types I do not really understand where they come from. They all start with "<>" and seem to have the "IsNestedPrivate" - Flag set to true:
[image]
That flag helps me to differenciate those types but what are those and why are they there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are classes the compiler has generated behind the scenes to implement functionality like lambda functions, `IEnumerable` functionality (via the `yield` keyword) and `async/await` state machines.

Chances are if you look at the attributes on the type then one will be [CompilerGenerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8)